# NoSuchMethodError ArrayOps trying to run basic Spark job

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am getting started with Apache Spark (on Windows 10), and things are not running as expected.
Using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2019.1, everything shows clean (no red underlines) but when I try to create a new SparkContext using

```
val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "RatingsCounter")
```

I get an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: \
scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)\
Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps;
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$
.stringToSeq(Utils.scala:2664)
```

Versions are as follows:
Scala 2.12.8
Java 1.8.0_171
Spark 2.4.1

Googling shows some responses, but none seem to reflect my issue.

Comment: Can you share the built.sbt or pom file ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75947449/run-a-scala-code-jar-appear-nosuchmethoderrorscala-predef-refarrayops